# Program coded to come from my email need to change where it's coming from server email...How?

Tags: html, excel, vba

So the issue is that in the testing phase my company wanted it to come from my email and not a random email. Now we want the emails to be sent from donotreply@company.com with the same information that the other email was sending. The new email will not be real (like mine).

```
Public Sub GetDates()
    Dim rw As Integer
    Dim subj As String
    rw = 2

    With ActiveSheet

        Do Until .Range("A" & rw) = ""
            If .Range("M" & rw) = "" Then
                If DateAdd("D", 30, Date) = .Range("G" & rw) Then
                    Call SendEmail(.Range("A" & rw), .Range("B" & rw), 30, .Range("L" & rw), False)
                ElseIf DateAdd("D", 15, Date) = .Range("G" & rw) Then
                    Call SendEmail(.Range("A" & rw), .Range("B" & rw), 15, .Range("L" & rw), False)
                ElseIf DateAdd("D", 7, Date) = .Range("G" & rw) Then
                    Call SendEmail(.Range("A" & rw), .Range("B" & rw), 7, .Range("L" & rw), False)
                End If
            End If

            If Day(Date) = 1 And .Range("G" & rw) < Date And .Range("M" & rw) = "" Then
                subj = subj & .Range("A" & rw) & ", " & .Range("B" & rw) & "--" & .Range("C" & rw) & " Report Past Due" & vbCrLf
            End If
            rw = rw + 1

        Loop

        If subj <> "" Then
            Call SendEmail(subj, "", 0, "supervisor@company.com", True)
            Call SendEmail(subj, "", 0, "Secondsupervisor@company.com", True)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
Public Sub demo_email(lName As String, fName As String, nDays As Integer, sTo As String)
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strBody As String

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

     iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
        Set Flds = iConf.Fields
        With Flds
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                           = ourserverhere"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
            .Update
        End With

    strBody = "Hi the testing from CDO" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
        "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
        "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
        "This is line 4"


    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .to = StrTo
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .From = """ReportdueReminder"" <donotreply@company.com>"
        .Subject = "Probation Report/IDP Report Due"
        .HTMLBody = strBody
        .Send
    End With


End Sub


Public Sub SendEmail(lName As String, fName As String, nDays As Integer, sTo As String, lastEmail As Boolean)

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = sTo
        If lastEmail Then
            .Subject = "Probation Report/IDP Report Due"
            .body = lName
        Else
            .Subject = "Probation Report/IDP Report Due" 'Enter subject line here
            .HTMLBody = lName & ", " & fName & "  <a href='http://www.websitehere.com'>Report 1</a> / <a href='http://www.otherwebsitehere.com'> Report 2</a> Due in " & nDays & " days" 'Enter body here
        End If
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your "With Outmail" add:

```
.SentOnBehalfOfName = "donotreply@company.com"
```